# How to create commandlink programmatically

Tags: jsf, seam, richfaces

We have a system built on seam/richfaces.
There's this webpage where the tables are rendered from dynamic context (from multiple different datasources, and each of them uses a different layout to represent essentially the same real world concept). As a result, this table is binded to a bean, and it's columns/layout are generated from this bean.

Now I need to add a command link on a specific column, equivalent to

```
<a4j:commandLink value="#{actBean.Ids}" action="#{actBean.genDetails}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{actBean.Ref}" value="#{cont}"/>
</a4j:commandLink>
```

in a JSF page.

The table is binded to a managed bean with

```
HtmlDataTable dataTable = new HtmlDataTable();
HtmlColumn column = new Column();
//some code to setup column name, value etcs
dataTable.getChildren().add(column);
//What do I do here to bind a commandlink with a property action 
//listener to column?
```

My question is, how do I do this programmatically?

Thanks!

Comment: @John @BalusC or @Bozho will show you how to. You have to bind your JSF component in your Managed bean in order to get your goal.

Comment: @Arthur I actually did the whole thing based on BalusC's tutorial. It's just that I couldn't find a proper way to bind the commandlink and propertyActionListener objects (on HtmlColumn objects), they are no where to be found in the richfaces/jsf api (or am I just missing them).

Comment: Be cool. @Bozho is online. He will show you how to

Comment: It's the in middle of the night here, so I couldn't quite grasp the question, being a bit sleepy. Will take a look in the morning. Before that, please provide some other code, which you are currently only describing

Comment: thx, I added more codes. The whole thing is probably too much detail. I hope the section I added gives enough idea to what I'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
HtmlAjaxCommandLink commandLink = new HtmlAjaxCommandLink();
commandLink.addActionListener(new SetPropertyActionListener(target, value));
column.getChildren().add(commandLink);
```

where `target` and `value` are  `ValueExpression`'s. These can be created with:

[`ExpressionFactory.getInstance().createValueExpression(ctx, expression, expectedType)`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/el/ExpressionFactory.html#createValueExpression%28javax.el.ELContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29)

And the required `ELContext` can be obained via `FacesContext.getCurrentContext().getELContext()`