# Autowire Annotation in Spring without using Component Scanning

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, ioc-container, autowired

Is it possible to autowire beans using the `@Autowired` annotation without using component scanning?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. `<context-component-scan .. />` is responsible for discovering beans annotated with `@Component`, `@Controller`, `@Service`, `@Respository`, etc.

In order to have annotations processed (`@Autowired`, `@Resource`, etc) you need `<context:annotation-config />`. Thus annotations are processed on beans that are listed in `applicationContext.xml`.

As far as I know, `<context-component-scan .. />` activates `<context:annotation-config />` automatically.

This is true for both spring 2.5 and 3.0. (thanks skaffman)

Comment: @Bozho Good (+1) Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458769/how-to-create-commandlink-programmatically

Comment: (+1) Yes, this is still the case in 3.0

Comment: I am using Spring 3.1 and the autowiring works only with <context-component-scan .. />. In fact I do not need <context:annotation-config /> to activate autowiring in beans

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried without component-scanning enabled, however I can confirm that @Autowire annotations works in Spring 3.0.x even with beans that are defined via XML.

Answer (score 0):

When using [AnnotationConfigApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html), annotation config processors are always registered, meaning that any attempt to disable them at the @ComponentScan level would be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If it is meant in the question that you should explicitly state:
- `<context:component-scan ...>` in your xml file(it enables `<context:annotation-config />`)
or
- @ComponentScan in your java config

Then the answer is - Yes, it is possible to enable component scanning without any of the stated above statements in your code or xml file.

Another approach is to use `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`  :

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context= 
new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("org.example.your.package");
```

Where "org.example.your.package" is your package for stereotyped annotated classes: @Component, @Repository, @Service, etc.
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext  will search for your beans in the base package and inner packages.

Answer (score 0):

No, we must use `@ComponentScan` if you are using java based configuration
(or) `<context-component-scan .. />` for xml based configuration.

*Note*: If you are not using any of the approaches no corresponding instances are created in AplicationContext.

and when you try to access a resource (http://localhost:8080/customers) will end up with

> WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/customers] in
> DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher